# Why are accelerator beam neutrino experiments built an angle off the beam direction?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, neutrinos, accelerator-physics

Was reading some papers and review articles on accelerator based neutrino experiments and this came up a few times. Most of what I could find mentions "shrinkage in neutrino energy spectra" and reducing the effects of electron neutrino impurities in a muon neutrino beam, but remains vauge.

For example, NOvA in the US is mentioned to be located 14 milliradians/12 km away from the beam direction.

I was just wondering what use to these experiments this has?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Off-axis beams, depending on the neutrino energy and the production source, can offer fluxes of neutrinos with a much more narrow range of energies. This is useful because the incoming neutrino energy is unknown on an event by event basis, and the neutrino flux is often a large source of systematic uncertainty in cross section and oscillation analysis.

The physics behind this is summarized in this excellent paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ex/0111033.pdf by Kirk McDonald. Basically for $\theta$ measured as the angle between the daughter neutrinos momentum and the direction of the parent pion's momentum, there exists a maximum neutrino energy possible. This implies that "many different pion energies contribute to the this neutrino energy, which enhances the neutrino spectrum at this angle-energy combination, θ ≈ (30-50 MeV)/Eν".

One can see this in the plot below from the paper which shows the relative neutrino flux as a function of neutrino energy and off axis angle.
[image: Relative neutrino flux vs neutrino energy and off axis angle]

Comment: I've edited my post to offer more explanation and a good reference.

Comment: Minor comment: please link to arXiv abstracts, not to PDFs.

Answer (score 13):

It depends on the particular experiment , and depends on the kinematics of decays. Example [here in this lin](https://cds.cern.ch/record/572119/files/ps-2002-051.pdf)k

> Also the use of off-axis neutrinos has been considered
> for NuMI and CNGS as a future option . The off-axis
> neutrino beams are of interest in case intense low-energy
> beams are required, e.g. for νµ → νe searches. The highintensity at small angles relative to the direction of the
> parent π is a peculiarity of the π → ν kinematics relating
> Eν to the decay angle in the laboratory frame. Of course,
> this set-up also requires new detector positions. Such a
> beam is foreseen for nu-JHF from the beginning